# Gvim throws the error 'E285: Failed to create input context'

Tags: gvim, error

I'm running into a bothersome issue I can't seem to solve myself.  When I open
gvim I receive the error `E285: Failed to create input context`

The error always comes twice, and looks to be related to XIM input.  Although
this is the first I've ever heard of IM and XIM as I am only ever working in
English.
I don't normally use gvim but I recently started using qutebrowser
and when I try to use gvim for input fields the errors pop up in a gui, and
require more action from me until I can actually type into the buffer.

Basic Specs:

> ```
> uname -a
> Linux pop-os 5.4.0-7634-generic #38~1592497129~20.04~9a1ea2e-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 22:43:37 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```

> ```
> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31) Huge version
> with X11-Athena GUI. +X11, +xim, +xfontset.
> ```

What I've tried:

1. Running gvim with `--clean` or like `gvim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE file.txt`.  I was hoping to narrow down if a certain config
   somewhere was causing the issue, but the errors prevailed even when specifying
   this clean startup.
2. Variations of the flags above, i.e. using my vimrc,
   taking some flags out etc.
3. Running `sudo gvim file.txt`.  This is the
   only way I've been able to open gvim without the errors.  Unfortunately not a
   valid solution as I would like to run with my configs and running with `-u\-U $HOME/.vimrc` gives way more errors from plugins and personal scripts as my
   home directory is now `/root/`.  last problem is I'm not wanting to type my
   password every time.
4. Trying to set the `guifont` when
   `has("gui_running")` and `has("x11")` are true.  Plus some other
   variants but this is the most direct logic path I could get to 'work'.
   However, this was a bug of it's own for me because even though I could set the
   guifont, and gvim could echo it back to me, the font, it's size, and other
   aspects would not actually change.  It also never subdued the error messages in
   question.  example of setting guifont: `set guifont=-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*`. I tried multiple styles of
   setting it but to no avail, so bonus points if someone konws how to fix this
   because I would like to change those settings.
5. Using the `-f file.txt` as suggested for some other bugs, but has no effect on the error messages.

Final Thoughts: I'm at a loss for new solutions as searches for the error only
results in a few similar issues from 2014 or older, that haven't fixed my
problem.  And since even the --clean startups were unsuccessful I can't even
drill down a certain config causing it, but using sudo actually works, but I am
unable to say why.

The one solution I haven't tried is the last post on the following link, to get
the source code and disable xim, but the instructions were just vague enough I
wasn't sure how to do it myself.
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gvim-complains-that-it-failed-to-create-input-context-926593/

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Hello, could you solve this problem? I have the same situation after upgrading to ubuntu 20 tls, thanks ...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when starting gvim from a shell script. Looking at the code vim ignores the fact that creating this context failed. It is just annoying the users with this message except when the "not a term" flag is set. To set that flag specify `--not-a-term` on the command line and the error message vanishes.

```
gvim --not-a-term filename
```

Comment: Somehow missed that flag back in the day when trying to solve this myself.  This was an instant fix and the use case I had for it I basically abandoned, and can now start using that workflow again.  My use case is using it to enter text into fields while using Qutebrowser.  Thanks for taking a second to post your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, after upgrade Ubuntu (20.04 TLS) worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove vim-athena vim-gui-common vim-gtk3
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk3
```